# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check class apache (in module x) that cannot access another apache class (in mod y)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to modularized java 16 projects as well as using the maven build system whilst trying to implement the program using IntelliJ, JAVAFX and APACHE POI-OOXML.

For simplicity, I am implementing a button's event handler that instantiates a class that is responsible for using Apache:
[ControllerCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABnIL.png)

The problem then happens here: [line 24 of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbvXS.png)

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1862)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8889)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacView.notifyMouse(MacView.java:127)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1859)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile (in module org.apache.poi.ooxml) cannot access class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile (in unnamed module @0x2db197a2) because module org.apache.poi.ooxml does not read unnamed module @0x2db197a2
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1088)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:182)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:814)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:735)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:660)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.create(OPCPackage.java:379)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.newPackage(XWPFDocument.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml/org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:130)
    at com.example.demo3/com.example.demo3.DataManager.createLessonWord(DataManager.java:24)
    at com.example.demo3/com.example.demo3.HelloController.onHelloButtonClick(HelloController.java:23)
    ... 56 more
```

I am completely new to all of these but I feel as though this line from the stack trace above is the culprit:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile (in module org.apache.poi.ooxml) cannot access class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile (in unnamed module @0x2db197a2) because module org.apache.poi.ooxml does not read unnamed module @0x2db197a2
```

Here is the module-info:

```
module com.example.demo3 {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml;


    opens com.example.demo3 to javafx.fxml;

    exports com.example.demo3;
}
```

My maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I would appreciate all help that I can get :)

Comment: Tried adding `requires org.apache.commons.compress;` in module-info.java solve the problem.

Comment: @samabcde Hi!! Thank you so much this worked!! I assumed that the IDE would warn me if I missed anything else just like it did when I was importing certain classes from Apache (such as warning me about putting a directive in module-info). At one point, I also began looking into JPMS but given by how much I didn't knew about about modularization, I didn't think I could do JPMS correctly too. Again, thank you!

Comment: I feel like the problem is in the poi ooxml library, it should include `requires org.apache.commons.compress;` in module.info. What I provided is just a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is due to missing requires in apache poi 5.0.0, which is fixed in  5.1.0.

*5.1.0 module-info.java*

```java
module org.apache.poi.ooxml {
    requires org.apache.poi.poi;
    requires org.apache.xmlbeans;
    requires org.apache.poi.ooxml.schemas;
    requires org.apache.commons.collections4;
    requires org.apache.commons.codec;
    requires org.apache.commons.compress;
    requires org.apache.commons.io;
    requires commons.math3;
...
```

*5.0.0 module-info.java*

```
module org.apache.poi.ooxml {
    requires org.apache.commons.collections4;
    requires org.apache.commons.codec;
    requires commons.math3;
...
```

Adding `requires org.apache.commons.compress;` in your project module-info.java can solve the problem.
But it looks like there are many `requires` added in version 5.1.0 which may be due to similar issue. So to prevent other similar error, I would suggest upgrading poi to version 5.1.0 or above.

Answer (score 0):

A piece as it says about a zip archive in the error.
There is no actual stream assigned with the place e,g, you have a String path but analogous there is not actually so much as an actual .io.File related part of the code.
There is however a constructor for such document that takes a Stream argument on construction.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how does this answer the question?

Comment: Hi Samuel! Thank you for helping me. I figured out the problem with the help of @samabcde and figured out that I was missing something from my module-info. I'll keep your advice in mind though!